# Don't know what date type I should use for statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE players(   id INT,     birthdate DATE,     PRIMARY KEY(id) );

SELECT * FROM players WHERE DATE-birthdate > 40;
```

The values of the birthdates should be in this format: *10-jun-1964*

And with the second SQL statement I want to select all from table players that are *older than 40*.

I know that those 2 statements are incorrect, but I have built them as far as I could to give you an idea of how it needs to be.

Is there anybody that can help me what exact type the birthdate field should be, and fix my second statement? I have been looking around for a solution and it's kind of confusing.

Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATE` is the proper data type to store dates in MySQL. Use [`DATEF_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to output the dates in the format of your choice (you need `'%d-%b-%Y'`).

Finding everyone over the age of forty requires constructing a date that is forty years ago from the current date:

```
SELECT *
FROM players
WHERE birthdate < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 40 YEARS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a date is fine. You can check by [subtracting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) 40 years from today.